# Какое из полей отвечает за размер GWLP_USERDATA

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Какое из полей структуры `WNDCLASSEX` отвечает за размер получаемых данных из `GetWindowLongPtr` путем извлечения поля `GWLP_USERDATA`,
`cbClsExtra` или `cbWndExtra`?

P.S. Предрасположение записи нескольких указателей и считывание данных с использованием смещения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни то, ни другое. Вызов `GetWindowLongPtr` c параметром `GWLP_USERDATA` возвращает значение, ранее сохраненное вызовом `SetWindowLongPtr` с этим параметром. Для получения байт, выделенных в соответствии с параметром `cbWndExtra` следует указывать в качестве аргумента `GetWindowLongPtr` индекс байта. Для получения байт, выделенных в соответствии с параметром `cbClsExtra`, следует также указывать индекс байта как аргумент для `GetClassLongPtr`.

Comment: Т.е. сохранить данные в дополнительную память окна больше чем размер `LONG_PTR` не выйдет?

Comment: @Yami Почему же не выйдет, выйдет. Но получать их надо не через `GWLP_USERDATA` а по индексу байта. На самом деле проще выделять экстра байты самому и сохранить указатель в `GWLP_USERDATA`.